Image viewer that supports multiple selection of thumbnails, cut and paste in a folder?
I use:
$ screenfetch -n | grep 'OS\|DE\|WM' && systemctl --property=Id,Description show display-manager.service
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
 DE: MATE 1.24.0
 WM: Metacity (Marco)
 WM Theme: Ambiant-MATE
Id=lightdm.service
Description=Light Display Manager

I want to organize some images that are on attached storage (network share or smartphone), by viewing their thumbnails in the enclosing folder, and then making a multi-selection (e.g. with shift+mouse click), making a Cut (Ctrl-X), and moving them to another location (local storage or network share).
I could have done this directly in the file manager (in Mate, it is caja, counterpart to nautilus) - the problem is that all thumbnails here get stored in local storage "in ~/.thumbnails/ or ~/.cache/thumbnails/" ( Where are the thumbnails of a new image located? ) ... and as I might have a massive amount of images in e.g. network share directories, I do not want to use the local storage space (which may be limited) for these thumbnails, and thus I do not want to enable showing of thumbnails "always" ( image preview from remote drive ).
In the default image viewer on MATE, Eye of MATE, it is possible to enable "Image Collection", which will show thumbnails of all images in a directory which is good - however, even if I can make a multiple thumbnail selection with shift+mouse click, whenever I right-click on this multi-selection, it gets reset and only the thumbnail the mouse was pressed over gets selected, and there is no Cut command either (and I'm not even sure it does NOT save thumbnails in local home directory). So I cannot use this for my use case.
I've found nomacs mentioned somewhere; this one allows for a list of thumbnails of images in the current directory to be shown ( Panel / Thumbnails ) which is good, and it seems to reconstruct the thumbnails each time it is started, which means it likely does not save thumbnails in local home directory ( which is also good ) - however, you cannot multi-select thumbnails with shift + mouse click, and there seems to be no Cut command either.
Note, once I've executed this Cut command on the multi-selection, I would want to just Paste the group of original images directly in, say, a network share folder - and have the OS move them there.
Is there any software on Ubuntu that would allow for the functionality I'm looking for, and support my use case?
